# limit log file and create a new one in php slim3 monolog

Tags: php, logging, slim, monolog

I am using slim3 with monolog from composer 
my dependencies is looks like that:

// monolog

```
$container['logger'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['logger'];
    $logger = new Monolog\Logger($settings['name']);
    $logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor());
    $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler($settings['path'], $settings['level']));
    return $logger;
};
```

I did not manage to set limit(filesize) for those logs 
basically, my log file name looks like: server-[date].log

I want to create a new log when it exceeded the 5MB  for example:

```
 server-[todaydate].log
 server-[todaydate]-1.log
 server-[todaydate]-2.log
```

Comment: I don't see a number `5` in your code. Try, then come back with some code.

Comment: Don't know how to do that. asking for help

Comment: you can find last log file, then get it size by filesize() function in php. then you can check if file size of last log file is greater than 5 mb create new one else write to last log file.@tuz

Comment: Do you insist on doing this from your PHP code? Or other methods are OK? Because you can achieve this using some other tools like `logrotate` utility. Monolog has a `RotatingFileHandler` but it rotates log files based on date and time, not size. They recommend using `logrotate` even for this type of rotation. Have a look at this https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php

Comment: How Can i use logrotate in my slim.php . (windows env)

Comment: There are some answers to similar question here https://serverfault.com/questions/358172/equivalent-of-logrotate-for-windows